# Java Semaphore - How to get used permits

Tags: java, semaphore

We can get remain permits though `availablePermits()`

how to get `usedPermits()` or `maxPermits`  at runtime (e.g. The max permits are loaded from db and the db value may be mutated after the semaphore created)?

Of course I can memorize the maximum permits in the memory but I wondered whether there is a simple way to do this

Comment: Little unclear to me.When you create a semaphore,you must provide the permit,then usedPermit=value provided to semaphore constructor - availablePermit().Can you provide any usecase or code snippet what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @RawAliasCoder I've make a short description, can you have a look again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, if you don't keep track of the original number yourself. Alternatively, you could easily extend Semaphore to have said capability(example implementation at the bottom).

In theory(and in the Java implementation), a semaphore does not have any concept of the "original" number of permits. With the defined semantics of a semaphore, you could very well initialize it with 0 permits, and require some permits to be "released" before any could be aquired. In practice I have never come seen a semaphore used in this manner, but that is how a semaphore is defined.

From the Java [Semaphore documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

> There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must have acquired that permit by calling acquire(). Correct usage of a semaphore is established by programming convention in the application.

So as you can see, if we don't know the "max permits" ourselves, the way semaphores are designed, they have no way of telling us either.

If you think of a semaphore as a wrapper around an int(which is in many ways what it is), it becomes quite clear:

Imagine we have the following sequence:

```
int permits = x;
permits--;
permits++;
// More unknown decrements/increments
permits--;
```

Getting the number of permits now is easy. Telling you how many has been used is impossible without either knowing `x` or the sequence of operations in the meantime.

---

Example of extending Semaphore to have a `usedPermits` method.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class UsedTrackingSemaphore extends Semaphore {
    private int originalPermits;

    public UsedTrackingSemaphore(int permits) {
        super(permits);
        originalPermits = permits;
    }

    public UsedTrackingSemaphore(int permits, boolean fair) {
        super(permits, fair);
        originalPermits = permits;
    }

    public int usedPermits() {
        return originalPermits - availablePermits();
    }
}
```